# A seemingly untranslatable sentence

Tags: словоупотребление

On a website for practicing languages, I composed a story with the following line about a café in Indonesia that serves an exotic coffee:

> Там варят самый вкусный и крепкий кофе в мире - Копи Лувак. —
>   прошептал он медленно и загадочно, причём у Наташи слюнки потекли уже
>   от одного названия.

My intention was to intimate that the name of the coffee was so exotic, that Natasha's mouth watered at the mere sound of it. In other words, the name of the coffee sounded so delicious that her mouth watered even before tasting it.

One of the "redactors" on the site, corrected it as follows:

> — прошептал он загадочно, растягивая каждое слово, отчего у Наташи тут
>   же потекли слюнки.

I answered that his sentence is good, but that it doesn't express the notion that the name of the coffee sounded so seductive to Natasha that it made her mouth water, and that furthermore, I refused to believe that in a language as rich as Russian, such a thing isn't possible.

He went on to wrote the following:

Задал ты мне задачку!:) Сказать по-честному, я не могу уместить всю полноту замысла в рамках одного короткого предложения... Возможно, что будет хорошо звучать следующим образом: "...прошептал он загадочно, растягивая каждое слово; тембр его голоса помноженный на выразительность звучания самого названия тут же захватили воображение Наташи, не оставив и нотки уныния в её душе и наполнив всё вокруг неё ароматом обжариваемых на открытом огне тёмных, как южная ночь, пухленьких кофейных зёрен...."

Кроме того, хочу заметить (это лично моё мнение), когда мы употребляем выражение "потекли слюнки", то, наверное, мы говорим про самого себя, а не про кого-то ещё. Например, " - Слушай, я даже не знаю, что тебе предложить... Ну давай возьмём свиной шейки полкилограмма, пожарим её на мангале с лучком, красным перцем и соевым соусом, запьём всё это армянским коньячком... Как думаешь? - Да у меня уже слюнки потекли, блин! Давай бери уже, наконец, и поехали к тебе на дачу!" Может быть, допустимо будет сказать так: "Ну что, потянуло дымком-то, а? Потекли слюнки?". Однако, как мне кажется, когда мы ведём повествование от третьего лица, как в твоём случае, то говорить о ком-то, "у неё потекли слюнки", звучит несколько неестественно.

Is there no way to translate this into Russian more succinctly? 
Here is the original sentence in English:

> There they brew the most delicious and richest coffee in the world -
>   Kopi Luwak." he whispered slowly and mysteriously, while Natasha's
>   mouth watered at the mere sound of the name.

Comment: That's be Russian translators. "Boromir smiled".

Comment: http://aveleen.livejournal.com/2262652.html

Comment: just a side note: Russian uses capital letters less extensively than English. Sort names, unless they are brand names, are not capitalized in Russian: Arabica, Robusta and Kopi Luwak would be *арабика*, *робуста* and *копи лювак*. In older texts even the brand names could start with a lowercase: *кока-кола*, *пепси-кола*, *лаки-страйк*.

Comment: @Quassnoi: It's funny you should say that because in my original story, it was копи лувак, yet almost every single person who reviewed it changed it to Копи Лувак: http://lang-8.com/579537/journals/66382232321982733216712148870422331541

Comment: that would be correct if it were a brand name, which it is not. Rosenthal: *общепринятые названия цветов, плодов пишутся со строчной буквы, например: анютины глазки, иван-да-марья, белый налив, папировка, ренклод, розмарин*.

Comment: btw, *мадам* is not capitalized either :)

Comment: also, not sure about all subtleties of English "asked nodding his head", but in Russian *кивая головой* would mean he was nodding repeatedly while talking, like a Chinese doll. If it's not the case, you should use *кивнув* (if he raised his head after nodding) or *склонив голову* (if he left his head inclined). *Кивая головой* is somewhat tautological anyway and generally frowned upon by purists.

Comment: I meant nodding his head steadily, knowingly while titillating her with the prospect of coffee... :)

Comment: "On a website for practicing languages" - could you please give a link to it?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Certainly - it's Lang-8.com

Comment: His first sentence is good for your meaning, your first sentence is not so good: use причём only as a last resort, because it fails to connect two events in one thought. «Так что» is the best option. When communicating, don't make non-existent problems out of the void, and you won't have to listen to solutions to such problems. The last paragraph is irrelevant, it's just a chat, and your friend explicitly told you so. “Это моё мнение” is often used to mean “Now I'm just beginning to chat, follow me if you like”.

Comment: And what, pray tell, is the non-existent problem that I created out of the void?

Comment: Well, he said a phrase that means just what you ask, and then you said you need something else, so he began thinking, believing you had some other problem, something more mystical; it was very easy to be mistaken. When a Russian begins thinking, that's like a mad bus crashing through its road. :)

Comment: Aha, got you. Perhaps I overthought it. I actually have a better understanding of what he meant now than I did back when I wrote this. I've been reading a lot more Russian and I think that helps. Thank you for all your wonderful answers, by the way. You have a great way of explaining things.

Comment: Haha, sometimes I feel like my questions are so mundane. I'm glad you find them interesting :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version is fine (I'd just replace `причём` with `так, что`, note the comma), and the *redaktor* has no idea what they're talking about.

> Кроме того, хочу заметить (это лично моё мнение), когда мы употребляем
>   выражение "потекли слюнки", то, наверное, мы говорим про самого себя,
>   а не про кого-то ещё.

That's plainly and simply a false impression. It *could* be a little on the colloquial side, but that's got nothing to do with who it's said about. And the tongue-in-cheek presentation of that patch of purple prose they go on to produce doesn't make it any less horrible. A parody can't afford to be clumsy, and *тембр его голоса помноженный на выразительность звучания самого названия тут же захватили воображение Наташи* is clumsy as heck on top of its dodgy syntax and punctuation.

You have to watch out for people overcomplicating things to create an illusion of competence. As a professional translator I can admit that I, too, have my moments of questionably pedantic judgement.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming exactly what I suspected. I'm also a professional translator and refuse to believe that anything can't be rendered succinctly in another language.

Answer (score 1):

Out of context I can't say if you want to translate "her mouth watered" literally.

If you do, you don't use *потекли слюнки*, it is a figure of speech.

I'd go with this:

> "Там варят самый вкусный и ароматный кофе в мире — *копи лювак*", — шептал он ей протяжно и загадочно. От одной лишь мелодии названия Наташин рот наполнился слюной.

Normally it would be *звуки названия* but this makes a parasitic alliteration.

If you want to say the sound of name made her crave a cup of coffee, your version is ok, though I would still drop that *причём* and made it two sentences.

Comment: *Рот наполнился слюной* sounds oddly physiological to me. I did just edit my own answer, prompted by second thoughts about the stylistic register of *потекли слюнки*, but it's not like "her mouth watered" is austerely "literary" either. In the end I think `потекли слюнки`'s status as established phraseology makes it the best fit.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: yes, but this seems to be used in physiological sense more often than I might imagine. Just on Google's first page: *The aroma of the chocolate made her mouth water, and her stomach let out a hungry gurgle*, — from a Harlequin book, too.

Comment: Yes, *her mouth watered* is perhaps less likely to be purely metaphorical; and yet it's a figure of speech rather than, as it were, a statement constructed from scratch on an empirical basis, and that should make the reader more readily gloss over the literal mental imagery than *рот наполнился слюной*.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: just in case: I'm with you and I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> There they brew the most delicious and richest coffee in the world -
>   Kopi Luwak." he whispered slowly and mysteriously, while Natasha's
>   mouth watered at the mere sound of the name.

Там заваривают кофе, вкуснейший и богатейший в мире — копи-лувак, — произнес он так таинственно и медленно, что Наташа почти почувствовала его привкус от одного только звучания этого имени.